# How to increase the expiry time of the token when user logged in using node js and firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication

Actually when a user logged in, then i create a token for that user but that token expires after 1 hour in firebase. Then again user have to logged in again.

So what i am trying to acheive is after token expires, automatically a new token will generate for the user so he/she does not have log in again and again and he/she will be there on the app for longer duration of time.

Here is my code for token generation when user logged in:-

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
    const user = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    const { valid, errors } = validateLoginData(user);

    if (!valid) return res.status(400).json(errors);

    firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
        .then((data) => {
            return data.user.getIdToken();
        })
        .then((token) => {
            return res
                .status(302)
                .json({ message: "successfully logged in", data: [{ token: token }] });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            if (err.code === "auth/wrong-password") {
                return res
                    .status(403)
                    .json({ message: "Wrong credentials, please try again" });
            } else return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
        });
};
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: read all the option, may be useful. https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: "Then again user have to logged in again." That is not how it's supposed to work. The Firebase clients auto-refresh the token every hour, in a way that is transparent to the user and (typically) to your application code. How are you detecting that the user needs to log in (again)?

Comment: When a user logged in token generated for the user. But after 1 hour this token got expired. And again user have to log in. So i want to increase the expiry time of the token so that it wont expired in 1 hour.

Comment: I want that this token got expired after 1 day or after 1 weak. So that when the user comes to my application he remains logged in for whole 1 day or 7 days. After that again he logged in. How can we achieve this? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: @HarshaHR the link you have shared is not helping me out

Comment: @AmanSingh your comment is repeating what you already said. As I commented: the ID token is auto-refreshed by the Firebase SDK, and you should have to do anything for that. How are you detecting that the user needs to log in (again)?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen ID token is not getting refreshed by the Firebase SDK. The code which i have shared generates token for the user and when i use that token after 1 hour It shows token expired please login again

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. There's no way to extend the expiration time of a ID token that is generated by one of the built-in providers. They expire an hour after being generated. The SDK will automatically create a new ID token just short of the old one's expiration, and then use the new token. If you use the ID token outside of the SDK, you should not cache it and get the token from the SDK each time you use it. At no point should the user have to provide their credentials again for any of this though.